# Potential Mem leak: Malloc for block and free for parts of the block?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am working with legacy C++ code that reserves a block of memory using malloc and divides it up into parts that are freed separately. Something like this:

```
const int N_floats_per_buffer = 100;
const int N_buffers = 2;
//reserve buffers en bloque
float * buffer = (float*) malloc(N_float_per_buffer * N_buffers * sizeof(float));
//then this block memory is divided into sub-blocks
float * sub_buffer[N_buffers];
for(int j = 0; j < N_buffers; ++j)
{
    sub_buffer[j] = buffer + j*N_floats_per_buffer;
}
//do something with the buffers...
//...
//finally: memory is freed for the individual buffers
for(int j = 0; j < N_buffers; ++j)
{
    if(sub_buffer[i]!=NULL) free(sub_buffer[j]);
}
```

It is actually even more confusing in the real code but I think I have captured the essence of it.

**My question is**: is that a memory leak?

Comment: It's an invalid use of  `free`: You can only `free` what you've `malloc`ed (`calloc`ed, `strdup`ed, ...). Your `sub_buffer`s are pointers into existing memory, not handles to allocated memory. But you should `free(buffer)` when you're done.

Comment: @walnut I have removed the C tag because the code is compiled using MSVC version 1900. Concerning the variable length arrays: I mistyped and forgot const in front of the integer length variables. I corrected it in the edit. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @geo Yes, that is what I meant. `const` resolves it, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a memory leak. It is worse, undefined behavior.

You can only call `free` on a pointer returned from `malloc` (or `calloc`, etc.). You are not allowed to call `free` on a pointer pointing somewhere else in the returned storage block. Doing that causes undefined behavior.

---

Also on a more pedantic side, `malloc` does not create any objects and pointer arithmetic requires the pointer to point to an element of an array object for it to have well-defined behavior in C++. Therefore you technically already have undefined behavior when you do

```
buffer + j*N_floats_per_buffer
```

although probably all compilers behave as expected (even though the standard made no guarantees). This was only resolved recently for C++20, where the required array will be created implicitly.

One should almost always only use `new`/`delete`, not `malloc`/`free` in C++.

Comment: I have just read up on 'free' on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). It says: "The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), or aligned_alloc() (since C11). " which is absolutetly what you said as well. The only thing I am wondering is the (since C11) appendage. Does it mean that before C11 it was not undefined behaviour?

Comment: And one more question: would it also be undefined behaviour if only the 0-th element of the array is freed:
free(sub_buffer[0])
in that case it would point to the block allocated by malloc, or not? (I know this is still terrible code)

Comment: @geo First of all you should look at the C++ version of the page if you are writing C++ code: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free. The "*(since C11)*" note applies only to the "*, or aligned_alloc()*" part. (There should be a box around the text to indicate that). That is because `aligned_alloc()` was added to the C standard only with C11. In previous iterations it doesn't exist. The rest of the sentence always applied. On the C++ page you will see the equivalent for C++.

Comment: @geo If you free only `sub_buffer[0]` (and only once), then there is no problem. `sub_buffer[0]` points to the same address as the pointer returned from `malloc`. There will not be undefined behavior on the `free` and there will not be any memory leak in that case. My other note about pointer arithmetic undefined behavior would still apply, but that is not really a practical concern.